# How can I open an ftp server in Chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, ftp

When I open an ftp address (e.g. ftp://localhost/some/path) it open "Choose an app" in Chrome. I've tried passive-ftp and some other things in internet options which didn't work. Is there a way to just open it in Chrome without the choose app dialog?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FTP support in Chrome is gone. Although dropping FTP [was pushed back due to the pandemic](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/google-reenables-ftp-support-in-chrome-due-to-pandemic/) and was simply [disabled by default](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6246151319715840), it has since been removed.

In earlier versions, you could go to `chrome://flags` and re-enable FTP, though this is no longer possible.

However, you should be looking for a different solution like a dedicated FTP client (FileZilla, Cyberduck, …).

Answer (score 21):

Update: ftp:// support in Chrome is now entirely gone even removed from chrome://flags [as of M95](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6246151319715840)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, bot.

Comment: Upvoted just to counter the bot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open files from ftp server, just type "ftp://192.168.1.48:2221" (enter your IP address) in windows file explorer,

[image]

Comment: But the question was about opening it on the browser.

Comment: This is awesome though. I never thought to do this in the file explorer +1